# How can I use priority queue in SWI-Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, priority-queue, dijkstra, a-star

I am trying to implement the *A* algorithm* in **SWI-Prolog**. I have a graph whose each state consists of the following values `(Cost_So_Far, Heuristic, "Doesn't Matter", "Doesn't Matter", "Doesn't Matter")` and I want to insert the state into a priority queue according to Heuristic which is an integer. How can I do this?

Comment: Please read "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)".

Comment: Since [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) is an enhancement to [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) why not start with that? At RosettaCode is [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) in many programming languages including [Prolog](http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Prolog)

Comment: A check of RosettaCode for [A*](http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) shows that there is no entry for Prolog.

Comment: This claims to have A* in Prolog in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020596/astar-prolog), did not verify.

Comment: Another question show A* in Prolog in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24630245/1243762)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a "heap" library, which is an implementation of the concept of "priority queue". There's a heap Prolog implementation by Richard O'Keefe floating around. SWI-Prolog also comes with a heap implementation in its "heaps" library by Lars Buitinck. Logtalk (which runs on several Prolog systems, including SWI-Prolog) also includes max- and min-heaps derived from Richard's original implementation. Using the heuristic value as the key as [Boris](http://web.archive.org/web/20170526022225/https://stackoverflow.com/users/1812457/boris) suggested, a heap should be more efficient than a list that you would have to resort every time you add a new pair.

Some useful links:

[SWI-Prolog heaps library](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/heaps.pl)

[Logtalk heap protocol](https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/blob/master/library/heaps/heapp.lgt)

[Logtalk min-heap and max-heap implementations](https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/blob/master/library/heaps/heaps.lgt)

Answer (score 2):

One easy way is to use a `Key-Value` pair list, which has the form:

```
[1-state(Cost_so_far, ...), 2-state(...), 3-state(...)]
```

Your integer value from the heuristic would be the key, compound term with the `state` functor (of whatever arity you need) would be the value. Note that this is the conventional way of keeping a list of pairs. You can use matching to get them out, for example, the state at the head of the queue would be:

```
[Heuristic-state(A, B, C)|QueueRest]
```

You should probably use the built-in [keysort/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=keysort/2) for sorting it (very efficiently) every time you have added new states at the top of the queue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic implementation of priority queues.
I just started learning Prolog.
If any better way to implement priority queues, please comment down below.

```cpp
takeout(X,[X|R],R).
takeout(X,[F|Fs],[F|S]):- takeout(X,Fs,S).

delete_elem([H|T]):- min_p([H|T],99,MinP) , search_minp(MinP , [H|T] , Num) , 
                     takeout((Num,MinP),[H|T],Z) , write(Z).

ins([],L,L).
ins([(Num,Priority)|T],L,[(Num,Priority)|Z] ):- ins(T,L,Z).
/* here i used ins function to append (Num,Priority) to a existing queue
if [(99,2) , (90,1) , (96, 3)] this is priority queue. if want to add (93,4)
ins([(93,4)] , [(99,2) , (90,1) , (96, 3)] ,Z).
Z = [(99,2) , (90,1) , (96, 3) , (93,4)]
*/

min_p([],Min,Min).
min_p([(Num,Priority)|Z],X,Y):- Priority < X , Min is Priority , min_p(Z,Min,Y).
min_p([(Num,Priority)|Z],X,Y):- Priority > X , min_p(Z,X,Y).

/* min_p here I used to find the minimum priority from the given priority queue.
X should be INT_MAX
min_p([(99,2) , (90,1) , (96, 3) , (93,4)],999,Y).
Y = 1 .
*/

search_minp(Priority,[(Num,P)|T],Num):- Priority is P.
search_minp(Priority,[(Num,P1)|T],X):- search_minp(Priority,T,X).

/* search_minp is used to search element corresponding to minimum priority.
if this is our priority queue [(99,2) , (90,1) , (96, 3) , (93,4)]
search_minp(1,[(99,2) , (90,1) , (96, 3) , (93,4)],Z).
Z = 90.
*/
```