# How to solve 15-puzzle paradigm in Prolog with Manhattan & Hamming Heuristics

Tags: search, prolog, a-star, heuristics, sliding-tile-puzzle

I have this implementation of the 15-puzzle game, using Prolog (Swipl). I have already implemented the A* search using Manhattan heuristic, but now I need to add hamming heuristic.

Do yo know how to implement it?

```
:- op(400,yfx,'@'). 

resolver(Estado,MovimientosSolucion) :- evaluar(Estado,0,F),
                                        buscarSolucion([Estado@0@F@[]],S), reverse(S,MovimientosSolucion).

evaluar(Estado,Profundidad,F) :-  evaluarCoste(Estado,Coste),
                                  F is Profundidad + Coste.

buscarSolucion([Estado@_@_@MovimientosSolucion|_], MovimientosSolucion) :-  solucion(Estado).
buscarSolucion([B|R],S) :-  expandir(B,Sucesores),
                            insertarTodos(Sucesores,R,ListaAbiertos),
                            buscarSolucion(ListaAbiertos,S).

insertarUno(B,ListaAbiertos,ListaAbiertos) :- nodoRepetido(B,ListaAbiertos), ! .

insertarUno(B,[C|R],[B,C|R]) :- costeMenor(B,C), ! .
insertarUno(B,[B1|R],[B1|S]) :- insertarUno(B,R,S), !.
                                insertarUno(B,[],[B]).

insertarTodos([F|R],ListaAbiertos1,ListaAbiertos2) :- insertarUno(F,ListaAbiertos1,ListaAbiertos3),
                                                      insertarTodos(R,ListaAbiertos3,ListaAbiertos2).
                                                      insertarTodos([],ListaAbiertos,ListaAbiertos).

nodoRepetido(Estado@_@_@_, [Estado@_@_@_|_]).

costeMenor( _@_@F1@_ , _@_@F2@_ ) :- F1 < F2.

expandir(Estado@Profundidad@_@S,Sucesores) :- findall(Sucesor@Profundidad1@F@[Movimiento|S],
                                          (Profundidad1 is Profundidad+1,
                                          mover(Estado,Sucesor,Movimiento),
                                          evaluar(Sucesor,Profundidad1,F)), Sucesores).

solucion(1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10/11/12/13/14/15/0).

manhattan(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P, Coste) :-  a(A,CosteA), b(B,CosteB), c(C,CosteC), d(D, CosteD),
                                                      e(E,CosteE), f(F,CosteF), g(G,CosteG), h(H,CosteH),
                                                      i(I,CosteI), j(J,CosteJ), k(K,CosteK), l(L,CosteL),
                                                      m(M,CosteM), n(N,CosteN), o(O,CosteO), p(P,CosteP),
                                                      Coste is CosteA + CosteB + CosteC + CosteD + CosteE + CosteF + CosteG + CosteH + CosteI + CosteJ + CosteK + CosteL + CosteM + CosteN + CosteO + CosteP.

evaluarCoste(Tablero,Coste) :- hamming_distance(Tablero,Coste).

mover(TableroInicial,TableroFinal,moverArriba) :- moverArriba(TableroInicial,TableroFinal).
mover(TableroInicial,TableroFinal,moverAbajo) :- moverAbajo(TableroInicial,TableroFinal).
mover(TableroInicial,TableroFinal,moverDerecha) :- moverDerecha(TableroInicial,TableroFinal).
mover(TableroInicial,TableroFinal,moverIzquierda) :- moverIzquierda(TableroInicial,TableroFinal).

moverArriba(A/B/C/D/0/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,0/B/C/D/A/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverArriba(A/B/C/D/E/0/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/0/C/D/E/B/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverArriba(A/B/C/D/E/F/0/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/0/D/E/F/C/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverArriba(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/0/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/0/E/F/G/D/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverArriba(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/0/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/0/F/G/H/E/J/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverArriba(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/0/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/0/G/H/I/F/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverArriba(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/0/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/F/0/H/I/J/G/L/M/N/O/P).
moverArriba(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/0/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/F/G/0/I/J/K/H/M/N/O/P).
moverArriba(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/0/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/0/J/K/L/I/N/O/P).
moverArriba(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/0/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/0/K/L/M/J/O/P).
moverArriba(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/0/P,A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/0/L/M/N/K/P).
moverArriba(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/0,A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/0/M/N/O/L).

moverAbajo(0/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,E/B/C/D/0/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverAbajo(A/0/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/F/C/D/E/0/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverAbajo(A/B/0/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/G/D/E/F/0/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverAbajo(A/B/C/0/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/H/E/F/G/0/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverAbajo(A/B/C/D/0/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/I/F/G/H/0/J/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverAbajo(A/B/C/D/E/0/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/J/G/H/I/0/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverAbajo(A/B/C/D/E/F/0/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/F/K/H/I/J/0/L/M/N/O/P).
moverAbajo(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/0/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/F/G/L/I/J/K/0/M/N/O/P).
moverAbajo(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/0/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/M/J/K/L/0/N/O/P).
moverAbajo(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/0/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/N/K/L/M/0/O/P).
moverAbajo(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/0/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/O/L/M/N/0/P).
moverAbajo(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/0/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/P/M/N/O/0).

moverDerecha(0/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,B/0/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverDerecha(A/0/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/C/0/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverDerecha(A/B/0/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/D/0/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverDerecha(A/B/C/D/0/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/F/0/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverDerecha(A/B/C/D/E/0/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/G/0/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverDerecha(A/B/C/D/E/F/0/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/F/H/0/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverDerecha(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/0/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/J/0/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverDerecha(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/0/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/K/0/L/M/N/O/P).
moverDerecha(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/0/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/L/0/M/N/O/P).
moverDerecha(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/0/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/N/0/O/P).
moverDerecha(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/0/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/O/0/P).
moverDerecha(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/0/P,A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/P/0).

moverIzquierda(A/0/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,0/A/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverIzquierda(A/B/0/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/0/B/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverIzquierda(A/B/C/0/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/0/C/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverIzquierda(A/B/C/D/E/0/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/0/E/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverIzquierda(A/B/C/D/E/F/0/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/0/F/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverIzquierda(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/0/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/F/0/G/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverIzquierda(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/0/K/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/0/I/K/L/M/N/O/P).
moverIzquierda(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/0/L/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/0/J/L/M/N/O/P).
moverIzquierda(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/0/M/N/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/0/K/M/N/O/P).
moverIzquierda(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/0/O/P,A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/0/M/O/P).
moverIzquierda(A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/0/P,A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/0/N/P).

% coste en distancias de cada posicion 
a(0,6). a(1,0). a(2,1). a(3,2). a(4,3). a(5,1). a(6,2). a(7,3). a(8,4). a(9,2). a(10,3). a(11,4). a(12,5). a(13,3). a(14,4). a(15,5).
b(0,5). b(1,1). b(2,0). b(3,1). b(4,2). b(5,2). b(6,1). b(7,2). b(8,3). b(9,3). b(10,2). b(11,3). b(12,4). b(13,4). b(14,3). b(15,4).
c(0,4). c(1,2). c(2,1). c(3,0). c(4,1). c(5,3). c(6,2). c(7,1). c(8,2). c(9,4). c(10,3). c(11,2). c(12,3). c(13,5). c(14,4). c(15,3).
d(0,3). d(1,3). d(2,2). d(3,1). d(4,0). d(5,4). d(6,3). d(7,2). d(8,1). d(9,5). d(10,4). d(11,3). d(12,2). d(13,6). d(14,5). d(15,4).
e(0,5). e(1,1). e(2,2). e(3,3). e(4,4). e(5,0). e(6,1). e(7,2). e(8,3). e(9,1). e(10,2). e(11,3). e(12,4). e(13,2). e(14,3). e(15,4).
f(0,4). f(1,2). f(2,1). f(3,2). f(4,3). f(5,1). f(6,0). f(7,1). f(8,2). f(9,2). f(10,1). f(11,2). f(12,3). f(13,3). f(14,2). f(15,3).
g(0,3). g(1,3). g(2,2). g(3,1). g(4,2). g(5,2). g(6,1). g(7,0). g(8,1). g(9,3). g(10,2). g(11,1). g(12,2). g(13,4). g(14,3). g(15,2).
h(0,2). h(1,4). h(2,3). h(3,2). h(4,1). h(5,3). h(6,2). h(7,1). h(8,0). h(9,4). h(10,3). h(11,2). h(12,1). h(13,5). h(14,4). h(15,3).
i(0,4). i(1,2). i(2,3). i(3,4). i(4,5). i(5,1). i(6,2). i(7,3). i(8,4). i(9,0). i(10,1). i(11,2). i(12,3). i(13,1). i(14,2). i(15,3).
j(0,3). j(1,3). j(2,2). j(3,3). j(4,4). j(5,2). j(6,1). j(7,2). j(8,3). j(9,1). j(10,0). j(11,1). j(12,2). j(13,2). j(14,1). j(15,2).
k(0,2). k(1,4). k(2,3). k(3,2). k(4,3). k(5,3). k(6,2). k(7,1). k(8,2). k(9,2). k(10,1). k(11,0). k(12,1). k(13,3). k(14,2). k(15,1).
l(0,1). l(1,5). l(2,4). l(3,3). l(4,2). l(5,4). l(6,3). l(7,2). l(8,1). l(9,3). l(10,2). l(11,1). l(12,0). l(13,4). l(14,3). l(15,2).
m(0,3). m(1,3). m(2,4). m(3,5). m(4,6). m(5,2). m(6,3). m(7,4). m(8,5). m(9,1). m(10,2). m(11,3). m(12,4). m(13,0). m(14,1). m(15,2).
n(0,2). n(1,4). n(2,3). n(3,4). n(4,5). n(5,3). n(6,2). n(7,3). n(8,4). n(9,2). n(10,1). n(11,2). n(12,3). n(13,1). n(14,0). n(15,1).
o(0,1). o(1,5). o(2,4). o(3,3). o(4,4). o(5,4). o(6,3). o(7,2). o(8,3). o(9,3). o(10,2). o(11,1). o(12,2). o(13,2). o(14,1). o(15,0).
p(0,0). p(1,6). p(2,5). p(3,4). p(4,3). p(5,5). p(6,4). p(7,3). p(8,2). p(9,4). p(10,3). p(11,2). p(12,1). p(13,3). p(14,2). p(15,1).
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: you could be interested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14769596/874024) answer

Comment: I've quickly implemented the 15-puzzle by straight modification (and enhancement) of my code for 8-puzzle. Are you interested ?

Comment: Well it can be cool to see :D I'm searching for an implementation with A* Algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solver for 8-puzzle, extended... maybe it will use too much memory. It implements simply a greedy heuristic. Could be interesting to extend it with A*...

```
/*  File:    fifteen_puzzle.pl
    Author:  Carlo,,,
    Created: Jul  9 2014
    Purpose: solve 15-puzzle
*/

:- module(fifteen_puzzle,
      [fifteen_puzzle/3
      ]).

:- use_module(library(nb_set)).
:- use_module(library(plunit)).

%%  fifteen_puzzle(+Target, +Start, -Moves) is nondet.
%
%   public interface to solver
%
fifteen_puzzle(Target, Start, Moves) :-
    empty_nb_set(E),
    solve(E, Target, Start, Moves).

%%  -- private here --

solve(_, Target, Target, []) :-
    !.
solve(S, Target, Current, [Move|Ms]) :-
    add_to_seen(S, Current),
    setof(Dist-M-Update,
          (  get_move(Current, P, M),
         apply_move(Current, P, M, Update),
         distance(Target, Update, Dist)
          ), Moves),
    member(_-Move-U, Moves),
    solve(S, Target, U, Ms).

%%  get_move(+Board, +P, -Q) is semidet
%
%   based only on coords, get next empty cell
%
get_move(Board, P, Q) :-
    nth0(P, Board, 0),
    coord(P, R, C),
    (   R < 3, Q is P + 4
    ;   R > 0, Q is P - 4
    ;   C < 3, Q is P + 1
    ;   C > 0, Q is P - 1
    ).

%%  apply_move(+Current, +P, +M, -Update)
%
%   swap elements at position P and M
%
apply_move(Current, P, M, Update) :-
    assertion(nth0(P, Current, 0)), % constrain to this application usage
    ( P > M -> (F,S) = (M,P) ; (F,S) = (P,M) ),
    nth0(S, Current, Sv, A),
    nth0(F, A, Fv, B),
    nth0(F, C, Sv, B),
    nth0(S, Update, Fv, C).

%%  coord(+P, -R, -C)
%
%   from linear index to row, col
%   size fixed to 4*4
%
coord(P, R, C) :-
    R is P // 4,
    C is P mod 4.

%%  distance(+Current, +Target, -Dist)
%
%   compute Manatthan distance between equals values
%
distance(Current, Target, Dist) :-
    aggregate_all(sum(D),
              (   nth0(P, Current, N), coord(P, Rp, Cp),
              nth0(Q, Target, N), coord(Q, Rq, Cq),
              D is abs(Rp - Rq) + abs(Cp - Cq)
              ), Dist).

%%  add_to_seen(+S, +Current)
%
%   fail if already in, else store
%
add_to_seen(S, L) :-
    %term_to_atom(L, A),
    findall(C, (nth0(I, L, D), C is D*10^I), Cs),
    sum_list(Cs, A),
    add_nb_set(A, S, true).

:- begin_tests(fifteen_puzzle).

show_square(R) :-
    findall(Row, (between(1,4,_), length(Row, 4)), Rows),
    append(Rows, R),
    nl, maplist(show_row, Rows).
show_row(R) :-
    format('~t~d~3+~t~d~3+~t~d~3+~t~d~3+~n', R).

show_solution(P, []) :-
    show_square(P).
show_solution(P, [M|Ms]) :-
    show_square(P),
    nth0(C, P, 0),
    apply_move(P, C, M, U),
    show_solution(U, Ms).

target(  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,0]).

start(0, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,0,13,14,15]).
start(1, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,10,11,12,9,13,14,15]).

test(0) :- runtest(0).
test(1) :- runtest(1).

runtest(N) :-
    target(T),
    start(N, S),
    fifteen_puzzle(T, S, R),
    format('solution of ~d: ~w~n', [N, R]),
    show_solution(S, R).

:- end_tests(fifteen_puzzle).
```

you can use `?- run_tests(fifteen_puzzle).` for a simple test.